# Replace keystroke in Borland C++ Builder 6

Tags: c++builder, keystroke

I must replace keystroke when user typing in TextBox.
When user type 123,456,789 text box must contain 123.456.789.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `OnKeyPress` Event and test to see if the `Key == ","`, change it to `"."`.

Answer (score 0):

One "low" level solution:

You can play with GetKeyState() from WINAPI
That should allow You to change the input.

[Keyboard actions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd458621(VS.85).aspx)

Or try this:

WM_..for ','

[Key codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd375731(VS.85).aspx)

some code:

```
case WM_KEYDOWN: 
        switch (wParam) 
        { 
            case VK_OEM_COMMA: 

                //Your processing code
```